# Создание текстовой ссылки в Telebot

Tags: python, telebot, google-maps

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Python при использовании библиотеки Telebot создать текст, содержащий адрес, по клику на который на телефоне пользователя откроются Гугл-карты... ?

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать markdown:

```
markdown = '''
[text](URL)
'''
```

Текст-ссылка будет выглядеть так:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '[текст ссылки](ссылка)', parse_mode='Markdown')
```